# Question about continuity of a function from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R.$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

> Consider the function $f : \Bbb R^2 \longrightarrow \Bbb R$ defined by $$
> f(x,y) = \left\{
>         \begin{array}{ll}
>             \frac {x^4y} {\sqrt {x^6 + y^3}} & \quad \text {if}\ (x,y)  \neq (0,0) \\
>            \  0 & \quad \text {if}\ (x,y) = (0,0).
>         \end{array}
>     \right.
> $$
> Prove that $f$ is not continuous at $(0,0).$

I have tried by taking the paths $y = mx^2,$ for different values of $m$ for approaching towards $(0,0).$  But along all such paths the double limits as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ are zero. Which paths should I take then? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try the path $(x(t),y(t)) = (t,t^2)$. You need the $y$ term to be at least as 'dominant' as the $x$ term in the denominator.

Comment: This function is not even defined at $(\pm 1, -1).$

Comment: $f$ is not defined along $y=-x^{2}$.

Comment: @copper.hat your path is the parametric form of $y = x^2,$ which is already taken care of.

Comment: Find a sequence $(x_n, y_n)$ such that $\lim (x_n,y_n) = (0,0)$ but $\lim f(x_n, y_n) \neq 0$. For example, let $(x_n, y_n) = (1/n, m_n/n^2)$. For proper $m_n$ near $-1$, we can make $|f(x_n, y_n)|>1$.

Comment: @Anacardium The value is ${ 1 \over \sqrt{2}}$ along that path. In fact, for your path the limit is ${m \over \sqrt{1+m^3}}$, so you have a valid answer there.

Comment: $(\pm 1, 1)$ does not count. You are only interested in a neighborhood of the origin. But $y=-x^{2}$ shows that $f$ is **not even defined in any neighborhood of the origin** so $f$ is not continuous at the origin.

Comment: Here's an idea. Take $y = x$ and do the limit as $x \to 0^-$. Then, $0 = \lim_{(x,y) \to 0} \frac{x^4 y}{\sqrt{x^6 + y^3}} = \lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{x^5}{\sqrt{x^6 + x^3}} = -\infty$. This is very clear if you graph it but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy some calculus textbooks allow for a discussion on multivariable limits even when the function isn't defined for particular points in a neighborhood around the origin.

Comment: @MatthewPilling The domain  of $f$ is specifically mentioned as $\mathbb R^{2}$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I want you to be aware of this feature in many textbooks in the (likely) event that other questions arise like this one.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy even if the domain of $f$ were accurately identified we could still examine this limit as long as we're considering paths in the set $\{(x,y):y\neq-x^2\}$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy if we replace $y$ by $|y|$ in the denominator then I think there will be no issue. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be easier to see if we rewrite the function with the sum of cubes formula

$$\frac{x^4y}{\sqrt{x^2+y}\sqrt{x^4-x^2y+y^2}}$$

Given that the function is not defined on $x^2+y=0$, use the path $x^2+y = x^n$ for some $n>2$

$$f(x,x^n-x^2) = \frac{x^{4+n}-x^6}{\sqrt{x^{3n}-3x^{2n+2}+3x^{n+4}}} = \frac{x^6}{x^{2+\frac{n}{2}}}\frac{x^{n-2}-1}{\sqrt{x^{2n-4}-3x^{n-2}+3}}$$

which goes to $-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ when $n=8$